# Infinispan distributed task execution

Tags: java, task, distributed, infinispan

I am aware of simple distributed task execution (Using Distributed Executor Service), for example [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/blob/master/distexec/src/main/java/org/infinispan/tutorial/simple/distexec/InfinispanDistExec.java) and [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/clustered-cache/src/main/java/org/infinispan/quickstart/clusteredcache), However the mechanism used is to serialize the callable and transport it to destination for execution, as I said this works for simple cases, many a times it wont be feasible to searlize every thing, for example from callable lots of classes would be referred to get a task done, in this case everything should be transported (many a times not possible, even if it is possible, it would take humongous time to transport accross, there by killing the purpose), what would be required instead is to assume that the classes exists at the target system and simply invoke it (the way hadoop works), 
I am not sure if there exists such execution model in infinispan?

Comment: Create an issue with Infinispan team https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7000

Answer (score 1):

If you provide externalizers for these callables, and both callables and externalizers are configured and deployed in all nodes (required), there's no need to ship those classes around. Detailed information on how to define externalizers can be found [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#plugging_infinispan_with_user_defined_externalizers).

Comment: I want to avoid Serialization/Externalization.. for simple hello world like cases, it is okay, however for real time it is not feasible/practical/recomended... for example, your callable would be talking to business layer, which in turn would talk to dao layer/external layer, plus it would used tons of classes to get the job done... serializing/externalizing all these classes only to make infinispan happy, would be a big no no.. serealizing/externalizing just the parameters/data would be fine, the way it works in hadoop... any thoughts??

Comment: Sending your business layer object through the wire is always a bad idea. What you should od instead is to extract a minimal set of objects required for your task (significant refactoring might be involved at this step), make that task Externalizable and use it for distributed execution. If it's not possible in your case, you might want to consider dividing computation into steps (possibly connected with queues). In that case look up some information about Event Driven Architecture (with some new concepts like Reactive stuff etc).

Comment: Btw, if you like how it works with Hadoop, you can use Infinispan as a backend for Hadoop, giving you the ability to store data in memory. See [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-hadoop) and some examples can be found [here](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-hadoop/tree/master/samples/). We've also published a few blog posts on the integration with Hadoop, check [here](http://blog.infinispan.org/search/label/hadoop).